# При попытке создать ключ получаю ValueError: Cannot serialize

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
class Groups(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)

    class Meta():
        verbose_name = 'группу'
        verbose_name = 'Группы'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Profile(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        verbose_name = "профиль"
        verbose_name_plural = "профиля"

    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',)
    user_referrer = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name="referrer", null=True, unique = False)
    last_seen = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now())
    group = models.ForeignKey(Groups, default = Groups.objects.get(name = 'Пользователь'))

    def __str__(self):
        return _('User: %(user)s | Referrer: %(referrer)s') % {
            'user': self.user,
            'referrer': self.user_referrer
        }
```

Получаю ошибку

> ValueError: Cannot serialize: 
>   There are some values Django cannot serialize into migration files.
>   For more, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#migration-serializing